# Can not find the folder i created on my device

Tags: android, file

i use `File class` to create folder on android but this folder is not showing in explorer of my computer when i plugged my tablet.

i proceed like this :

```
File pdfFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                 File.separator + "MyFolder");
```

My app configuration :

```
minSdkVersion 21    
targetSdkVersion 25
```

My tablet android version is `6.0`

Can you help me please?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try that code

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), YOUR_FOLDER_NAME);
if (!path.exists()) {
    path.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: my code is working ! i can found the folder on tablet but when my tablet is plugged  i can't get it from my computer ! thanks